# SQL Server lag window and custom logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, lag

I am working on this dataset https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=447a5d2c33b04346e70dab0a8d098655

Custom logic: grouped by name, testcentre, coursename, testtype. If a retest is taken, then scores are compared - if higher the highest one precedes or original score.

There are cases where a retest is not associated with original test (missing data or data entry error) in this case if date difference 10 days or higher, the record is taken as original.

Lag: Based on above selected row, if a lag window exists between the remaining set of records example within 4 days, then the highest score record shall be picked up.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Sample data

```
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| recordid | Name  | testcentre | coursename | testtype | testscore |  testdate  | retestflag | Preferred_Output |                 RejectReason                  |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|        1 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 2019-02-01 |          0 |                0 |                                               |
|        3 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2019-02-02 |          1 |                1 | Better score in retest                        |
|        4 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | TOEFL    |        80 | 2019-02-04 |          0 |                0 | Within 4 days of previous test                |
|       21 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2018-02-02 |          1 |                1 | marked as retest without base.needs inclusion |
|        5 | Jack  | London     | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 2019-02-01 |          0 |                1 | Same or bad score in retest                   |
|        8 | Jack  | London     | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 2019-02-02 |          1 |                0 | Same or bad score in retest                   |
|        7 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | IELTS    |        70 | 2019-02-01 |          0 |                1 | Same score in retest                          |
|       11 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | IELTS    |        70 | 2019-02-02 |          1 |                0 | Same score in retest                          |
|       13 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | TOEFL    |       100 | 2019-02-04 |          0 |                0 | Within 4 days of previous test                |
|       55 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 2016-02-01 |          0 |                1 | Older test, no follow on                      |
|       60 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2019-08-01 |          0 |                1 | same score in retest                          |
|       61 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2019-08-02 |          1 |                0 |                                               |
|       62 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | TOEFL    |        80 | 2020-01-04 |          0 |                1 | More than 4 days, included                    |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Desired Output

```
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
| recordid | Name  | testcentre | coursename | testtype | testscore |  testdate  | retestflag | Preferred_Output |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
|        3 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2019-02-02 |          1 |                1 |
|       21 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2018-02-02 |          1 |                1 |
|        5 | Jack  | London     | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 2019-02-01 |          0 |                1 |
|        7 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | IELTS    |        70 | 2019-02-01 |          0 |                1 |
|       55 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 2016-02-01 |          0 |                1 |
|       60 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 2019-08-01 |          0 |                1 |
|       62 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | TOEFL    |        80 | 2020-01-04 |          0 |                1 |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Can you fix your dates so they are in the standard YYYY-MM-DD format.  I can't tell what the dates mean.  And a date difference of 10 days or 4 days?  The question is not clear.  Also, the difference between *which* dates?

Comment: when we compare record id 1,3,4 - 1 is original record and 3 is a retest. record 4 is within 4 days after 3.

Comment: in record id 21, it is flagged as a retest record, without any base record (date is on 2018 ) , these cases we may use 10 days difference.  shall change the date formats now for clarity.